# offset().top vs. offset from top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to perform some calculations via javascript / jquery in order to make elements in my webapp responsive. I understand that by using `object.offset().top` I'm able to obtain the number of pixels between the top of my content and the top of the object. However, part of my design is that certain elements stick to the top of the screen while the rest of it scrolls past, and then `object.offset().top` isn't useful in the same way that it was.

What I'd like to know: is there a method available for determining the distance between my object and the top of the user's screen (as opposed to between the object and the top of my content)? I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Cheers

Comment: have to work with window scrollTop along with offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a method available for determining the distance between my object and the top of the user's screen

Yes, there is – [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect):

> *“The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` properties describing the border-box in pixels. top and left are relative to the top-left of the viewport.”*

I made a (more than) crude example here, http://jsfiddle.net/7ceL8p3s/ – scroll the red box into view, and click on it – it will log the `TextRectangle` object to console each time you click, and you’ll see the `top` and `left` values are relative to the viewport. (The viewport of the jsfiddle result frame that is – go to http://jsfiddle.net/7ceL8p3s/show/ to see it in a full window.)

And if you scroll it so that the box goes partly out of view on the top viewport border, so that only a lower part of it is visible, you will get negative `top` values as well. (Same should happen for `left` if you have a layout where the element might be scrolled out of view to the left.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make this. I'll give it a shot.